# Extending numpy with cython

Tags: python, numpy, word-wrap, cython

I am trying to wrap a header file which has lots of functions like this

**test.h**

```
void test(int N, int* data_in, int* data_out);
```

so that I can use those from numpy.

Right now I have the following cython code:

**test.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int_t itype_t

cdef extern from 'VolumeForm.h':
    void _test 'test' (int, int*, int*)

def wrap_test(np.ndarray[itype_t, ndim=2] data):
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=1] out
    out = np.zeros((data.shape[0],1), dtype=np.double)
    _test(
        data.shape[0],
        <itype_t*> data.data,
        <itype_t*> out.data
    )
    return out
```

However, when I try to compile it I get the error:

```
Error converting Pyrex file to C:
(...)
Cannot assign type 'test.itype_t *' to 'int *'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This issue is currently being discussed on the Cython mailing list; apparently it stems from a small bug in one of the Cython libraries:

http://codespeak.net/mailman/listinfo/cython-dev

For the moment, one potential workaround is to use NumPy arrays of dtype np.long, and then to write 'ctypedef np.long_t itype_t' instead. Then you just have to make the C code happy with long ints instead of ints.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround that doesn't require you to change things from `int`s to `long`s: change the function signature in the `cdef extern from '...'` block.  Cython uses the declarations in a `cdef extern` block only to check types while generating the `.c` file, but the generated C code merely does an `#include "VolumeForm.h"`, so you can get away with it.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int_t itype_t

cdef extern from 'VolumeForm.h':
    # NOTE: We changed the int* declarations to itype_t*
    void _test 'test' (int, itype_t*, itype_t*)

def wrap_test(np.ndarray[itype_t, ndim=2] data):
    cdef np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=1] out
    out = np.zeros((data.shape[0],1), dtype=np.double)
    _test(
        data.shape[0],
        <itype_t*> data.data,
        <itype_t*> out.data
    )
    return out
```

Cython does not complain about the above.